# Is there a way to dynamically set border bottom to the last element, and sometimes the last two elements?

Tags: html, css, sass, grid

I've been struggling with this for a while. I have a dashboard showing some labels with values. The number of values in the dashboard are dynamic. I built this with grid so every time I have an odd number of values the last one gets it's own row. My mission was to make the last row of the dashboard to not use `border-bottom` since it ruins the look of it.

I tried using `:last-child` but that will only work when I have an odd number of values in my dashboard. Same goes with `:nth-last-child(-n+2)` which targets the last two elements when I have an even number of elements in my dashboard.

**Even:**

[image]

**Odd:**

[image]

Is there a way to dynamically set the last row to not use `border-bottom` in both cases when there's odd and even number of values in my dashboard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  gap: 2em;
  margin: 2em;
  bordr: 1px solid black;
}

.item{
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

.item:last-child,
.item:nth-last-child(2):nth-child(odd){
  border-bottom: none;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="item">2</div>
  <div class="item">3</div>
</div>


<div class="container">
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="item">2</div>
  <div class="item">3</div>
  <div class="item">4</div>
</div>
```

Try to select the :last-child and the :last-child only if its and odd element:

```
:last-child,
:nth-last-child(2):nth-child(odd){
   //...
}
```